# How to use InAppBrowser plugin?

Tags: visual-studio, cordova-plugins

In Visual Studio, I've downloaded the InAppBrowser plugin and am trying to use it like this:

```
<a onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank', 'location=yes');">testing</a>
```

When I click that link, I see this:

[image]

It obviously recognizes the plugin but why doesn't it rendering the webpage?